# Select a set of columns in dataframe to use for a for loop in R

Tags: r

If I have a data frame with column names like this...

```
[1] "subject"            "box"               "date"      "Total_Lever_Press"   "Total_CS_Mg_Ent"  
[6] "Total_NCS_Mg_Ent"   "K1"                "K2"                "K3"                "K4"               
[11] "K5"                "K6"                "K7"                "K8"                "K9"               
[16] "K10"               "K11"               "K12"               "K13"               "K14"              
[21] "K15"               "K16"               "K17"               "K18"               "K19"              
[26] "K20"               "K21"               "K22"               "K23"               "K24"              
[31] "K25"               "L1"                "L2"                "L3"                "L4"               
[36] "L5"                "L6"                "L7"                "L8"                "L9"               
[41] "L10"               "L11"               "L12"               "L13"               "L14"              
[46] "L15"               "L16"               "L17"               "L18"               "L19"              
[51] "L20"               "L21"               "L22"               "L23"               "L24"              
[56] "L25"
```

How can I just select the K1 through K25 columns to run a for loop equation on?

I've tried grep to choose a start column and end column, like...

```
number_of_trials <- 25
k_array <- grep("K1":number_of_trials, data)
```

But that clearly didn't work.

Edit: I would like number of trials to be the end parameter so that it could be changed per user. So it could be K1 to number_of_trials or L1 to number_of_trials

Edit2: I didn't mention the loop I wanted to do. I want to look through all of the K columns (per row), and count the number of times a column is greater than zero. Put that number in a new column and divide it by the number_of_trials.

Edit3: An example, The first row may look like this...

```
K1 K2 K3 K4 K5 K6 K7 K8 K9 K10 K11 K12 K13 K14 K15
0  3   4  1  3  0  0  0  0  1   5   6   7   8   0
```

So the equation would be 9/15 = 0.6 (because 9 columns for that row do not contain a zero). I only want the equation to be for each row in the dataframe between the select columns.

Edit4: Example for loop...

```
cols <- grep('K\\d+', names(data))
number_of_trials <- 25
data$probability <- 0
for (row in 1:nrow(data)) {
  data[row,"probability"] <- count(data[row,cols] > 0)/number_of_trials
}
```

Edit5: table with expected outcome

```
K1 K2 K3 K4 K5 K6 K7 K8 K9 K10 K11 K12 K13 K14 K15 Probability
0  3   4  1  3  0  0  0  0  1   5   6   7   8   0     0.6
0  2   3  1  3  0  0  0  0  1   0   0   0   0   0     0.33
0  3   2  1  3  0  0  0  0  1   5   6   7   5   0     0.6
0  3   1  1  3  0  0  0  0  1   5   6   7   8   1     0.66
0  0   0  3  2  0  0  0  1  0   0   0   0   0   0     0.2
```

original table...

```
K1 K2 K3 K4 K5 K6 K7 K8 K9 K10 K11 K12 K13 K14 K15 
0  3   4  1  3  0  0  0  0  1   5   6   7   8   0     
0  2   3  1  3  0  0  0  0  1   0   0   0   0   0     
0  3   2  1  3  0  0  0  0  1   5   6   7   5   0     
0  3   1  1  3  0  0  0  0  1   5   6   7   8   1     
0  0   0  3  2  0  0  0  1  0   0   0   0   0   0
```

So probability is 9/15=0.6, 5/15=0.33, 9/15=0.6, 10/15=0.66, 3/15=0.2

Answer:

```
data <- type.convert(data, as.is = TRUE)
cols <- grep('K\\d+', names(data))
data$Probability <- rowMeans(data[cols] > 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
data <- type.convert(data, as.is = TRUE)
cols <- grep('K\\d+', names(data))
data$Probability <- rowMeans(data[cols] > 0)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like in base R you can do -

```
cols <- grep('K\\d+', names(data))
data$Probability <- rowMeans(data[cols] > 0)
data

#  K1 K2 K3 K4 K5 K6 K7 K8 K9 K10 K11 K12 K13 K14 K15 Probability
#1  0  3  4  1  3  0  0  0  0   1   5   6   7   8   0       0.600
#2  0  2  3  1  3  0  0  0  0   1   0   0   0   0   0       0.333
#3  0  3  2  1  3  0  0  0  0   1   5   6   7   5   0       0.600
#4  0  3  1  1  3  0  0  0  0   1   5   6   7   8   1       0.667
#5  0  0  0  3  2  0  0  0  1   0   0   0   0   0   0       0.200
```

This will return proportion of values which are greater than 0 for each row.

**data**

```
data <- structure(list(K1 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), K2 = c(3L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 0L), K3 = 4:0, K4 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L), K5 = c(3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 2L), K6 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), K7 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L), K8 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), K9 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L), 
    K10 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), K11 = c(5L, 0L, 5L, 5L, 0L), 
    K12 = c(6L, 0L, 6L, 6L, 0L), K13 = c(7L, 0L, 7L, 7L, 0L), 
    K14 = c(8L, 0L, 5L, 8L, 0L), K15 = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: That didn't exactly work so I added a third edit

Comment: An example data helps, thanks. Can you check the updated answer?

Comment: that still didn't really work. I was thinking of something more like in my edit4. But that loop is not working.

Comment: @jc2525 I don't think you need `for` loop to do this. You can use my answer directly on the dataframe. I have shown an example dataframe and output for it. Can you check that and let me know if it works as expected? If you think it doesn't can you provide us with an example dataset with 5-10 rows at least and expected output for it.

Comment: Did you try my answer on it? I get the exact same output as your expected one. Edited the answer to show that. I also added your data in a reproducible format so that you anyone can copy it directly instead of typing it out.

Comment: yes, i ended up just getting "1" for probability

Comment: I think you have data of different class and they are not numbers. It is useful if you share data using `dput` like how I have in my answer. What does `class(data$K1)` return? Run `data <- type.convert(data, as.is = TRUE)` and try the answer again. Does that change anything?

Comment: "face palm"...thank you. Such a dumb oversight on the class. It works now. And thank you for the type.convert function. I wasn't aware of that :)